# Cannot pass an image imported through props

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const SquareIcon = icon => {
  return (
    <FlexContainer>
      <Icon src={icon} />
    </FlexContainer>
  )
}

const FlexContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 1rem;
`
const Icon = styled.img``

export default SquareIcon
```

And in this component, I try to import the images and pass the image as icon for the above component:

```
import SquareIcon from "./SquareIcon"
import TensorFlowIcon from "../images/images/tensor-flow.png"
import ScikitIcon from "../images/images/scikit.png"
import GoogleCloudIcon from "../images/images/google-cloud.png"
import PythonIcon from "../images/images/python.png"

const CourseDetails = () => {
  return (
      <IconGrid>
        <SquareIcon icon={TensorFlowIcon} />
        <SquareIcon icon={ScikitIcon} />
        <SquareIcon icon={GoogleCloudIcon} />
        <SquareIcon icon={PythonIcon} />
      </IconGrid>
    </GridContainer>
  )
}
```

This does not work, the images are imported correctly (Seen via my VSCode extension) but it shows Unable to load image [object Object] on the browser.

If I import the image directly in the SquareIcon component, it works normaly:

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import PythonIcon from "../images/images/python.png"

const SquareIcon = icon => {
  return (
    <FlexContainer>
      <Icon src={PythonIcon} />
    </FlexContainer>
  )
}

const FlexContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 1rem;
`
const Icon = styled.img``

export default SquareIcon
```

What's wrong here???

Answer (score 0):

I guess `import PythonIcon from "../images/images/python.png"` is static linking, which means it happens in the compile time.

There's a difference between a string and imported object. You can try to simply use url string so that your icon can be dynamically driven by that string.

Comment: After a while, it just works. I've done nothing, not even rebuild. I have no idea what happened.